# Change UTF-8-MAC to UTF-8

Tags: php, macos, encoding

I try to change UTF-8-MAC file name to UTF-8

Files are on Nas(linux)

My code are here.

```
// $tfile has the filename to change
$cnvFile = iconv("UTF-8-MAC","UTF-8",$tFile);
if ($tFile != $cnvFile){
    system("mv -n '". $tFile . "' '" . $cnvFile . "'");
```

However it is in vain.

`if $tFile != $cnvFile` returns true ,so system can recoginize difference between UTF-8-MAC and UTF-8

I use this from MacOS and NAS server is connected by `webdav`

I can access the folder like this `/Volume/NasShare/Myfile.png`

Comment: Is this Perl? Maybe tag it with a language.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It is PHP

Comment: Fun fact: aside from the `!=` (which should be `ne` in this context), this is also 100% valid Perl code.

Comment: @duskwuff Cool, I should have spotted that! Thanks.

Comment: @duskwuff I used to use perl 10 years ago though, PHP and perl is  quite similar. It's just the coincidence.

Comment: Neither https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/documentation/libiconv-1.15/iconv_open.3.html nor `iconv --list` mentions the encoding `UTF-8-MAC`, so what is the input encoding?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue today and I was finally able to fix it using the [`normalizer_normalize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php) PHP function to normalize Mac UTF-8 encoding.

```php
$normalizedUtf8 = normalizer_normalize($macUtf8String);
```

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer. How should that normalizer know which target encoding should be used?

Comment: Just click on the provided link to open the related PHP documentation page. The function use the default UTF8 normalization value value used by PHP as parameter. You can also find more information on this page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php or on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization